# Unable to use MySQL on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:42:05 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I've been trying to use MySQL on XAMPP but it's  showing this error. I can't seem to find the solution. Any help would be really appreciated. Before this I was also unable to start Apache but then I disabled World Wide Web Publishing Services and it's working fine on port 80 and 443. Does this error have anything to do with the previous error?

Answer (score 0):

maybe trying port 3306 will make your XAMPP can using MySQL, hope it help you

Comment: It's already running on port 3306. The moment I start it it shows MySQL running on port 3306 then after about a few seconds it shuts down.

Comment: @NoamaanMulla Please post the last 400 lines of your error log for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used XAMPP for a long time now, but yes I remember the same issue that happened to me. The other service might be taking the ports required by XAMPP.
You should stop both of them first.
To rectify it, one thing that you can do for sure is to: **Start XAMPP as an administrator**.
 This will allocate the required ports for the service.
Should work fine then.

Comment: I ran XAMPP as administrator but it's still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer to the question.**

Close XAMPP if it's open and go to in the following directory:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\backup
```

Copy everything in that folder and go to:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\data
```

Select everything in that folder and paste what you copied and run XAMPP as an administrator then start MySQL